# Docker cookbook not finding Docker file

Tags: dockerfile

I've got a Dockerfile I'm trying to build using the following code:

```
docker_image 'wafflehouse' do
  source '/root/dockerimages/CentOS'
  action :build_if_missing
  read_timeout 6000
  write_timeout 6000
end
```

Using test kitchen the builds fail:

```
Error executing action `build_if_missing` on resource 'docker_image[wafflehouse]'

No such image: sha256:4eda692c08e0a065cg91d74e82ffxxxxxxxx07b4341ad61fa61771cc4659af60

Docker::Error::NotFoundError
```

If I reference the Dockerfile directly in the code:

```
docker_image 'wafflehouse' do
  source '/root/dockerimages/CentOS/Dockerfile'
  action :build_if_missing
  read_timeout 6000
  write_timeout 6000
end
```

The build fails to find the files that are referenced in the Dockerfile to copy:

```
FROM centos

COPY wafflehouse.repo /etc/yum.repos.d
COPY wafflehouse-artifacts.repo /etc/yum.repos.d
COPY wafflehouse-snapshot-artifacts.repo /etc/yum.repos.d

RUN yum install -y net-tools

CMD ["bash"]
```

The files are in the same directory as the Dockerfile. Any ideas on either of these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have a problem with the `dockerfile` instead of Chef.
You should keep in mind that you are providing a relative path to the source of the files you want to copy.

In order to fix this, try using absolute paths for source and target paths, something like:

```
FROM centos

COPY /root/dockerimages/CentOS/wafflehouse.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/wafflehouse.repo
COPY /root/dockerimages/CentOS/wafflehouse-artifacts.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/wafflehouse-artifacts.repo
COPY /root/dockerimages/CentOS/wafflehouse-snapshot-artifacts.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/wafflehouse-snapshot-artifacts.repo

RUN yum install -y net-tools

CMD ["bash"]
```